# ArrayAdapter size is 2 but editText is null

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

[image]
Why Edit Text is null

```
    BusDatabase = new BusesDatabase(getActivity());
    List<String> list = BusDatabase.getAllPlaces();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    AutoCompleteTextView editText = (AutoCompleteTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
    editText.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working in a fragment, you need to reference the view through the inflated rootView of your fragment. so:

```java
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
EditText myEditText = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_edit_text);
```

and then work with your `myEditText`.